# Проблема с установленной библиотекой docx

Tags: python, python-3.x

Перед описание чуток про окружение:

- Операционная система  Linux Ubuntu
- Установлена: anaconda3
- Версия Python: 3.8.5 GCC 7.3.0

Произвел установку модуля docx для импортирования данных из программы в формат docx результатов вычисления.
Устанавливал при помощи команды:

```
 pip install python-docx
```

Все поставилось без проблем. Если я ввожу команду:

```
 helps('modules')
```

Отображается модуль docx.

```
Если ввожу:

help('docx')
```

Пишет:

```
problem in docx - ImportError: cannot import name 'Self' from 'typing_extensions' (/home/volk/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

Если попытаюсь запустить простейшую программу в которую импортировал модуль и попытался там создать файл с расширением docx и в него внес что-то типа строки с текстом "Привет" выдается ошибка:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'Self' from 'typing_extensions' (/home/volk/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

Такая же ерунда была на стац.компьютере, где стоит Винда. Там у меня есть две версии интерпретаторов python 3.7  и python 3.10 там была та же проблема если запускал от IDE Python 3.10, не было проблем с 3.7 после установки docx. Победил тем, что установил два раза  пакет, для 3.7 поставил и для 3.10. Теперь и работает для любого варианта Python'a .

Вопрос: Как решить проблему с работой библиотеки docx на ноутбуке, где у меня операц. система Linux Ubuntyu. понимаю, что проблема с версионностью и где-то не прописывается в служебном файле ссылка на docx (что-то с PATH),но я не знаю как починить.

Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Пробуйте устанавливать самую новую версию модуля typing_extensions

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, вышла новая версия typing-extensions, я обновил до 4.8 и все заработало без проблем. Если вы оформите в виде ответа. Я лайкну. Если не будете. Я оформлю ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пакет [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) - это пакет с новшествами типизации из новых версий Python (например тот же тип [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self), появившийся в Python 3.11), портированными для более старых версий Python (3.8 и выше), и просто с экспериментальными фичами из новых PEP.

Если выдает ошибку на отсутствующее имя `Self`, то похоже при установке `python-docx` установилась старая версия `typing_extensions`, нужно ее вручную обновить до самой новой версии.